# Proving that some element is the inverse in a group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we're working in a group $G$. Both the textbook and my professor seem to argue that if we're proving that some element is the group inverse (for example, $b^{-1} a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $ab$), it suffices to check either that it's a left inverse or that it's a right inverse.

This confuses me somewhat, as it is possible in theory for an element to be a left inverse but not a right inverse or vice-versa, but if some element has both a left and right inverse, they are equal and are the "proper" inverse. My question, I suppose, would be the following. Is the correct reasoning that we can, in effect, flip the implication arrow around? If some element is a proper inverse, it is both a left and a right inverse. Because $ab$ is an element of $G$, it has an inverse. That inverse is also unique and both a left and right inverse (and, further, the left and right inverses are themselves unique), so if I can find some left inverse, that must be the only left inverse, and it must also be "the" inverse.

This sounds a bit hand-wavy, so it would help if someone could tell me if I'm on the right track or explain it a bit better than I have.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Associativity implies that the left and right inverse are equal.

Suppose  $a'$ left inverse of $a$ and $a"$ right inverse of $a$,

$(a'a)a"=ea"=a"=a'(aa")=a'e=a'$ where $e$ is the neutral.

Comment: So because $ab \in G$, $ab$ has a right inverse, say $c$, so that $(ab)c = e$, so proving $(b^{-1} a^{-1})(ab) = e$ immediatley implies that $c = b^{-1} a^{-1}$, by what you just proved. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $ab=e$, then $(ab)^{-1}=e$, so $b^{-1}a^{-1}=e$, so $e=bb^{-1}a^{-1}a=bea=ba$.